# What is the right way of including FFF mocks in different files?

Tags: c, unit-testing, mocking, linker

I have a bunch of test cases I want to divide in 2 source files. These tests use fake functions created by FFF. When I try to include my fake headers in the 2 different source files, I get linker errors: `multiple definition of ... first defined here`. They are first defined in the source file that already included these mocks.

I need all mocks to be visible in both files. How can I include them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it [in this section, in the FFF README file](https://How%20do%20I%20reuse%20a%20fake%20across%20multiple%20test-suites?).

Basically, using the `DECLARE_FAKE_*` and `DEFINE_FAKE_*` macros